# How to train a keras model with predicted value?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

In keras we use `model.fit(X,y)` to train a deep neural network. The fit function requires input X and output y values to train a model. In one of my projects, I need to train a keras model with already available predicted output `y_pred`.

```
X   y   y_pred

7   1   0.2566005265
10  1   0.5516392291
5   0   0.6365937824
14  1   0.1750051752
2   1   0.69076036
4   0   0.0712530303
```

How can I train and update a **keras** model with predicted output?

something like this `model.fit(X,[y-y_pred],loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer="rmsprop")`

Edit:

I am not talking about a multi output model. I literally have predicted output `y_pred` which I want to use to find the loss `binary_crossentropy(y,y_pred)` and then update the weights.

Comment: You have to check how to build multi out put models in Keras. It is well defined in the section of Functional API in Keras docs

Comment: Are these predictions from some other model, or the same one?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I can't give up much details because I am experimenting with a new type of model and yes the predictions are from the same model. I know I can do this in tf or pytorch but was thinking to implement it in keras for easy prototyping.